# Stop printing after certain HTML tags

Tags: jquery, css

I have written the following script to print the page.

Is it possible to Not Print the HTML after the following tag

```
 <font class="productnamecolorSMALL colors_productname"><b>Related Items</b></font>
```

Meaning ignore the print after the above

```
<p>Click the button to print the current page.</p>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Print this page</button>
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        window.print();
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: I don't think the `print()` function would allow that, although if you make it a block such as a certain `<section>` you probably could mark that section with `display:none` when the `@media` type is `print`.

Comment: As Alexis has said.  Use a CSS style sheet that has those properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Alexis Wilke suggested add a print stylesheet.

This css will remove the first adjacent sibling of .productnamecolorSMALL from the printed page by using the adjacent sibling selector. You can use whatever css you want to mark what you want to remove or display differently while printing. So just edit the print stylesheet to your needs.

html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="/css/print.css" type="text/css" />
```

**css**

```
@media print{
  .productnamecolorSMALL+*{
    display: none;
  }
}
```